# How to structure an AWS Lambda with python in subfolders?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I'm struggling in figuring out how to properly set up a python Lambda in a subdirectory and have imports work correctly.  For example, if you don't put your python in the root folder as recommended by AWS and instead, put it in a src folder with a lambda_handler.py that is the main handler in there and then packages/folders inside that, so you might have src/api, as an example.  I am using the new SAM accelerate and they acknowledge a bug where it doesn't ignore the .aws-sam folder, so it will infinitely loop with the project in root, so they recommend a subfolder, but that greatly complicates things with Python, apparently.

I think I properly figured out how to get it to properly to read my own packages and modules in subfolders using **init**.py, but I can't get my requirements.txt to install, so they don't show up in the local build or the cloud build.  I have found quite a few StackOverflows that are seemingly on the subject, but none of them seem to work for me or give an example that I can follow that works.  The following is my structure:

`/
.aws-sam
└── src
    ├── app_folder_1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── example1.py
    ├── lambda_handler.py
    ├── app_folder_2
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── example2.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── template.yml`

I have an import of pymysql as an example and my dependencies for requirements.txt are never installed, so pymysql never is found.  I feel like things shouldn't be this difficult.  Can anyone assist?

UPDATE: I may have figured out the issue, which this post gave me a cluse to https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/1927  It appears that `sam invoke local` has the same issue with custom templates -- something I was utilizing -- and that isn't very intuitive, even though they claim that is working as intended.

UPDATE 2: Definitely assisted with my progress, but it still isn't working as intended.

Comment: I finally gave up and went back to root.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to return to this, so I figured I would post this here to assist others that may be struggling as Python is really finicky.

The following is the structure of a functional project in Lambda:

```
├── README.md
├── buildspec.yml
├── lambda_handler.py
├── locales
│   ├── en
│   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │       └── base.po
│   ├── es
│   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │       └── base.po
│   ├── fr
│   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │       └── base.po
├── my_project_name
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── python_file_1.py
│   ├── python_file_2.py
│   ├── python_file_3.py
│   ├── repositories
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── resolvers_1.py
│   │   ├── resolvers_2.py
├── requirements-dev.txt
├── requirements.txt
├── template.yml
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── tests_file_1.py
    ├── tests_file_2.py
    ├── tests_file_3.py
    └── tests_file_4.py
```

Note that the base.mo files are generated in the build in the same location as the base.po files and that requirements-dev.txt has dev-only libraries, such as pep8 for formatting and is only run within my local conda environments [I set up virtual environments for each project using miniconda].  The purpose of the resolvers in the nested repositories folder is to separate out the controller-like python files from the calls to the repositories to retrieve data.